# Conjugation of transformations which can be identified by a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, soft-question, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces

I mean such transformations of a Euclidean or Hilbert space like shifting by a vector, rotating a 3-dimensional Euclidean space around a vector, or projecting onto the line of a vector.
Let $v$ be a vector and $T_v$ a transformation of a type listed above and let $U$ be a rotation (if the space is Euclidean) or a unitary transformation (if the space is a Hilbert space). In all these cases,
$$T_{Uv}=UT_vU^{-1}\tag 1$$

What is the exact and general mathematical formulation of this lay observation? What does "a transformation which can be identified by a vector" mean mathematically?

### Edit

I'm afraid that the definition of "a transformation which can be identified by a vector" can just be "a mapping $v\mapsto T_v$ from a vector space into the space of its affine transformations that obey (1)". But then the question emerges are there any other such transformations besides the three mentioned above?